# Why assign the string 'prototype' to a variable then use it to set the prototype of an object?

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

I just came across this code for a [classList polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/blob/master/classList.js#L82) and I can't understand why the developer chose to do the following:

```
var protoProp = "prototype";
```

... later in the code...

```
ClassList[protoProp] = [];
```

What's wrong with `ClassList.prototype = []`? I can't think of any reason why they would do this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to be for minimisation, where that value can be converted into

```
ClassList[v]=[];
```

rather than

```
ClassList.prototype = [];
```

The `protoProp` variable is used several places instead of `prototype` and would save a few bytes in total

Comment: Very good point. Separately, it means that a minifier than does property renaming will leave that property name alone, which is obviously important. I'd expect any half-decent one to know to leave `prototype` alone, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - indeed, I don't think any of the minifiers would change the string value, nor mess with built in properties like `prototype`. We of course see this kind of optimization all the time with `window`, `document` and other common references that can't be minified without using some sort of variable, but I don't think I've seen it with `prototype` before, or at least I haven't specifically noticed it.

Comment: I do however wonder why a minifier couldn't do this optimisation on its own…

Comment: @Bergi - I'm guessing changing dot notation to brackets to save a few bytes, also could cause some unintended issues *(not sure what though ?)*

Comment: I don't think it can. Maybe it's just not easy enough to find a proper scope for the string constants.

Answer (score 0):

in my last project i needed to minify & obfuscate my code and i convert all objects like this

```
arr.length ===> arr["length"];
str.replace("a","") ===> str["replace"]("a","");
Element.prototype.colorize ===> Element["prototype"]["colorize"]
```

and every thing works very well
now i have strings 
`length` , `replace` , `prototype` , `colorize`
and we have multiple ways to obfuscate this strings to be more difficult to read.